# Raster to Point in ArcMap: export raster data to a point shapefile with geometry of a given point shapefile

Tags: arcmap, geometry, environment-variable, raster-to-point

I want to export a calculated raster to a point shapefile with predefined geometry (i.e. positioning and extent of the points). Points not covered by the raster should return empty values (e.g. `NoData`). It works for the positioning of the points, however it does not work for the extension of the points.

I do have:

- point shapefile `MyTemplatePoints.shp` as a template
- raster file `mytempr` calculated from template point shapefile above
- raster file `mycalcr` calculated from various input data in an `arcpy`-script
- point shapefile `MyCalculatedPoints.shp` exported from `mycalcr` with `Raster to Point (Conversion)`

The `arcpy`-script to calculate `mycalcr` contains the following command line:

```
arcpy.env.snapRaster = mytempr
```

By this, the centroids of the cells of `mycalcr` snap to those of `mytempr`. The two rasters have different extensions which is not a problem. Export of `mycalcr` to `MyCalculatedPoints.shp` is performed with `Raster to Point (Conversion)` with input parameters as shown to the left in the image. The points of `MyCalculatedPoints.shp` fit to the positioning of the points of `MyTemplatePoints.shp` as visible to the right in the image. However, the extension of `MyCalculatedPoints.shp` does not match the extension of `MyTemplatePoints.shp` as I would expect by `Environment Settings > Processing Extent`.

It seems to me that this processing is unsuitable to generate a point shapefile with larger extension than the raster itself (and to fill these points with empty values, e.g. `NoData`).

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The hint by *BERA* made me find the solution: use `Spatial Analyst Tools` > `Extraction` > `Extract Values to Points` and define the desired `Extent` and `Snap Raster` in the `Environment Settings`:

[image]